# Vector Network Analyzers: Bode100 vs Keysight P5000A

Tags: impedance, measurement, test, vna

I have been using Bode 100 machine earlier to measure Impedance and Phase of my piezoelectric transducer.
The frequency range i work in is from 10kHz to 2.5MHz.
I was just comparing this Bode100 with Keysight P5000A VNA as it is more coapct than Bode100. But was wondering if it is possible to do the same job of Bode100 of measuring Impedance and Phase over certain frequency sweep.
Which would be a overall better choice?
Thanks

Comment: Add links to the data sheets. You might want to read the data sheets yourself. It would make a better question if you quoted the parts of the datasheets that describe the measurement functions, and the frequency ranges over which those are supported, and pointed out where you are confused about them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the P5000A offers the same linearity and phase stability as the Bode 100 does. The Bode 100 has inherently high linearity due to the operational-amplifier technology used. The P5000A for sure uses RF technology that offers a higher frequency range but might not offer the same linearity. Best would be to try.